# No injectable field found in FXML Controller class for the id 'wall' Java fx Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

i'm programming a maze for a project for my university.
I created some scenes where you have to click on play to continue then you insert your name and surname then the code will create the maze etc.
I got some problems with scenebuilder and FXML files, when i create a rectangle in scene builder then i call it with the same id in java i got this error: **Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle.setX(double)" because "this.wall" is null** i checked everything, but i can't find the problem, in scene builder the scene has the controller class setted, also it worked for the other scene, only in this scene builder can't find the injectable field.
This is my code (it hasn't nothing in Labirynth Create but i already have some code to create the game, this is simplified for you to understand my problem)
Thank you so much.

```
package com.maze.Models;

import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;


public class Player {


    private BooleanProperty upPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty leftPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty downPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty rightPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty upRight = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty upLeft = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty downRight = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty downLeft = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    private BooleanBinding keyPressed = upPressed.or(leftPressed).or(downPressed).or(rightPressed).or(upRight).or(upLeft).or(downRight).or(downLeft);

    int row;
    int col;

   public Player ()
    {
        row=0;
        col=0;
    }

    @FXML
    private ImageView sprite;

    @FXML
    private Group scene;



    public void makeMovable(ImageView sprite, Group scene){
        this.sprite = sprite;
        this.scene = scene;

        movementSetup();

        keyPressed.addListener(((observableValue, aBoolean, t1) -> {
            if(!aBoolean){
                timer.start();
            } else {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }));
    }

    AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long timestamp) {

            if(upPressed.get()) {

                if (row>=0 && row<9)
                {

                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() - 75);
                    upPressed.set(false);
                    row++;
                }
                upPressed.set(false);

            }

            if(downPressed.get()){

                if (row>0 && row<=9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() + 75);
                    downPressed.set(false);
                    row--;
                }
                downPressed.set(false);

            }

            if(leftPressed.get()){

                if (col>0 && col<=9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() - 75);
                    leftPressed.set(false);
                    col--;
                }
                leftPressed.set(false);
            }

            if(rightPressed.get()){

                if (col>=0 && col<9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() + 75);
                    rightPressed.set(false);
                    col++;
                }
                rightPressed.set(false);
            }


            if(upRight.get()){

                if (col>=0 && col<9 && row>=0 && row<9)
                {

                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() + 75);
                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() - 75);
                    upRight.set(false);
                    col++;
                    row++;
                    System.out.println("Posizione attuale"+row+col);
                }
                upRight.set(false);
            }

            if(upLeft.get()){

                if (col>0 && col<=9 && row>=0 && row<9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() - 75);
                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() - 75);
                    upLeft.set(false);
                    col--;
                    row++;
                    System.out.println("Posizione attuale"+row+col);
                }
                upLeft.set(false);
            }

            if(downRight.get()){

                if (row>0 && row<=9 && col>=0 && col<9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() + 75);
                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() + 75);
                    downRight.set(false);
                    col++;
                    row--;
                    System.out.println("Posizione attuale"+row+col);
                }
                downRight.set(false);
            }

            if(downLeft.get()){

                if (col>0 && col<=9 && row>0 && row<=9)
                {
                    sprite.setLayoutX(sprite.getLayoutX() - 75);
                    sprite.setLayoutY(sprite.getLayoutY() + 75);
                    downLeft.set(false);
                    col--;
                    row--;
                    System.out.println("Posizione attuale"+row+col);
                }
                downLeft.set(false);
            }


        }
    };

    private void movementSetup(){
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W) {
                upPressed.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.A) {
                leftPressed.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.S) {
                downPressed.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.D) {
                rightPressed.set(true);
            }
            ///
            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.E) {
                upRight.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.Q) {
                upLeft.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.C) {
                downRight.set(true);
            }

            if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.Z) {
                downLeft.set(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

```
package com.maze.Models;

public class User {


       private String name, surname;



        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

}
```

```
package com.maze.Models;

public class Model {
    private static Model instance;
    private User user;

    public static synchronized Model getInstance(){
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new Model();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private Model() {
        this.user= new User();
    }

    public void createUser (String name, String surname)
    {
        user.setName(name);
        user.setSurname(surname);
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        System.out.println(user.getName());
    }



}
```

```
package com.maze.Models;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import java.lang.Cloneable;
import java.lang.Object;
public class Cella implements Cloneable {

    private Rectangle rect;


    public Cella()
    {
        rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.setX(75);
        rect.setY(75);
        rect.setHeight(70);
        rect.setWidth(70);
        rect.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    }
    public Cella (Cella temp)
    {
        temp.rect.setX(this.rect.getX()*2);
        temp.rect.setY(this.rect.getY()*2);
        temp.rect.setHeight(this.rect.getHeight());
        temp.rect.setWidth(this.rect.getWidth());
        temp.rect.setFill(this.rect.getFill());
    }

    public Rectangle getRectangle(){
        return rect;
    }

    public void editX(int x)
    {
        rect.setX(x);
    }

    public void editY(int y)
    {
        rect.setY(y);
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
      Cella temp= new Cella();
      temp.rect.setX(this.rect.getX());
      temp.rect.setY(this.rect.getY());
      temp.rect.setHeight(this.rect.getHeight());
      temp.rect.setWidth(this.rect.getWidth());
      temp.rect.setFill(this.rect.getFill());
      return temp;
    }


}
```

```
package com.maze.Views;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LabyrinthApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "/com/maze/FXML/Scene1.fxml"));

        Parent root = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,900);




        stage.setTitle("Labyrinth");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

```
package com.maze.ViewModels;

import com.maze.Models.Model;
import com.maze.Models.User;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class LabyrinthName {
    @FXML
    private TextField nametext;
    @FXML
    private TextField surnametext;
    @FXML
    private Button submitbutton;


    String Name, Surname;
    LabyrinthCreate create = new LabyrinthCreate();

    @FXML

    public void submit(ActionEvent event) throws Exception
    {
        Name = nametext.getText();
        Surname = surnametext.getText();
        Model.getInstance().createUser(Name,Surname);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "/com/maze/FXML/Scene3.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage window = (Stage) submitbutton.getScene().getWindow();

        window.setScene(new Scene(root,1000,900));
        window.setResizable(false);
        create.createLab(window);
    }

}
```

```
    package com.maze.ViewModels;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabyrinthController {
    @FXML
    Button playbutton;

    public void onPlayButtonClick() throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "/com/maze/FXML/Scene2.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        Stage window = (Stage) playbutton.getScene().getWindow();
        window.setScene(new Scene(root,1000,900));


        window.setResizable(false);

    }
}
```

```
package com.maze.ViewModels;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabyrinthCreate
{


    @FXML
    private Rectangle wall;

    public void createLab(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {


        wall.setX(100);
        wall.setY(100);

        System.out.println("tutto ok");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="900.0" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maze.ViewModels.LabyrinthController">
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
  </padding>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="900.0">
         <children>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="183.0" layoutY="306.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MAZE GAME ">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="64.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="playbutton" layoutX="326.0" layoutY="391.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onPlayButtonClick" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="218.0" style="-fx-background-color: grey;" text="Play" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="46.0" />
               </font>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow height="103.07" offsetX="6.0" radius="40.775" width="62.03">
                     <color>
                        <Color red="0.32894736528396606" green="0.3259015679359436" blue="0.3259015679359436" />
                     </color>
                  </DropShadow>
               </effect>
            </Button>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="513.0" layoutY="771.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Created by Antonella Sannino">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <ImageView fx:id="startRobot" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="617.0" layoutY="192.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../image/robot.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="900.0" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maze.ViewModels.LabyrinthName">
  <padding>
    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
  </padding>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="900.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="submitbutton" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="399.0" layoutY="472.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#submit" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="Submit">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <TextField fx:id="nametext" layoutX="283.0" layoutY="360.0" style="-fx-alignment: center;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="310.0" layoutY="344.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="33.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="surnametext" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="466.0" layoutY="360.0" style="-fx-alignment: center;">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="465.0" layoutY="343.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Surname">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="33.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="WHITE" layoutX="306.0" layoutY="235.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Insert your name">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Cooper Black" size="33.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maze.ViewModels.LabyrinthCreate">
   <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="wall" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="DODGERBLUE" height="200.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="200.0" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

[Scenebuilder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G9rn.png)

I was expecting scene builder to find the id for Rectangle class.

Comment: My guess is you're instantiating `LabyrinthCreate` manually. You need to interact with the controller instance managed by the `FXMLLoader`, as it's only that instance that has the FXML fields injected.

Comment: i added my full code

Comment: My guess seems to be correct. In `LabyrinthName`, you call `createLab` on an instance created with `new LabyrinthCreate()`. Since you manually created that instance, the FXML field was never injected. I assume that `Scene3.fxml` is associated with `LabyrinthCreate`. You need to get the instance by calling `FXMLLoader#getController()` (after the call to `load()`).

Comment: In LabirynthName i added loader.getController() as you said but i still got the same error, maybe i have to create the fxml and the loader in LabirynthCreate? 
Also yes you did understand what i was doing, thank you

Comment: You're saying `loader.<LabyrinthCreate>getController().create(window);` is throwing the _exact same_ `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I understood what you said, the right way was loader.<LabyrinthCreate>getController().createLab(window); thank you so much Slaw

Answer (score 4):

When you have an `fx:controller` attribute in the root element of the FXML file, then you must not instantiate the controller class yourself (possibly unless you're also defining a custom [controller factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory(javafx.util.Callback))). The `FXMLLoader` will instantiate the controller for you (via reflection by default) and it's only that instance which will have any `@FXML`-annotated fields injected. You can get this controller instance by calling [`FXMLLoader#getController()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController()) *after* the call to `load()`.

For example, let's say you have the following FXML file and associated controller class.

**Main.fxml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:controller="com.example.Controller">
    <Label fx:id="label"/>
</StackPane>
```

**Controller.java**:

```java
package com.example;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Controller {

    @FXML private Label label;

    public void setLabelText(String labelText) {
        label.setText(labelText);
    }
}
```

Then you'd load the FXML file, get the controller instance, and call `setLabelText` like so.

**Main.java**:

```java
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Assumes 'Main.fxml' is at the root of the class-path/module-path
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("/Main.fxml"));
        
        Parent root = loader.load();

        // Get *managed* controller instance (after call to 'load()')
        Controller controller = loader.getController();
        // Call method on the managed controller instance
        controller.setLabelText("Hello, World!");

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If the following was done instead (similar to your code):

```java
Controller controller = new Controller();
controller.setLabelText("Hello, World!");
```

Then a `NullPointerException` would've been thrown, because the controller instance is an *unmanaged* instance and thus the `label` field was never injected.

Answer (score 1):

In labirynthName i needed to add
loader.getController().createLab(window);

Comment: _In **class** `LabirynthName`_ you _needed to add ..._ Maybe post the corrected code showing where, exactly you added `loader.getController().createLab(window);`?